# Why doesn't Visual Studio make DateTime a Blue Key word?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

If I understand it correctly, Visual Studio is supposed to Color Data Types Blue. So why doesn't it do that with DateTime?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You question yourself why Int32 is not blue coloured? because it is not a `keyword` It is a `Type` and so it is Green coloured in VS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`int` is a keyword as defined in the [C# Language specs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all), whereas `DateTime` is a struct. If you use `Int32`, you'll notice that that too will turn to the same colour as DateTime because `Int32` is not a keyword (even though `int` is an alias for `Int32`).

The default colour settings in Visual Studio is to highlight `keywords` blue which is why the keywords you've shown are in blue.

Comment: Best overall answer so far.

Comment: int aka System.Int32 is also a struct that is not the issue for having an alias. For some reason DateTime is not considered as primitive as the number types, char, and string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: while a built in blue datetime or date keyword would be great at this point it would break alot of code that uses these names as local variables.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime is not a keyword; it is a struct, which is a ValueType, whereas a class is a Reference type. These are not considered primitives, so they are not colored unless you change the color in your VS settings.

Technically the keywords int, string, bool, and double are keywords, but they map to their Struct equivalent in the .NET framework. This way an int works the same in VB and C#.

So an int maps to Int32 Struct. They are colored blue to mimic primitive types as they are in other languages.

[Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: What's a "static struct"?

Comment: Though it is,  not the reason i don't believe since Double Int32 Int64 and other data type aliases do the same.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was thinking of DateTime.Now which is very common use. I corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is a class and your instantiating an object of a class, where as other primitive data types such as int, float are all keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I changed my Environment color scheme I lost some of the default code highlighting. By simply switching between other color themes(Blue,Dark,Light..) the code highlighting problem was resolved.

This can be done in TOOLS > Options > Environment

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding that your DateTime is black rather than colored I just got that when my VisualStudio config messed up and returned to default.

If you go TOOLS > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors then scroll down to "User Types (Value Types)" then change it to a different color syntax highlight of DateTime is restored (it seems to sometimes bug out and not highlight even through it's set to a color)